# show all the Images with one size in the web page with out decrese the quality

Tags: html, css

I want to show some images. I need them to have the same size and show the pictures from the middle to prevent them from decreasing in quality.

Comment: Add your code and give us more information regarding your question.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use this css

```
image{
max-width:100%;
max-height:100% 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your content there would be more that one way to do this. But this will also help you to middle align the image.

```
.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
 }
```

But my suggestion would be to make your question more understandable to what you already have, and what you really want.

Comment: actually I want to align the picture from the middle

Comment: I would suggest you give us an example of what you already have.

Comment: please go to http://digiato.com and see their picture many of them have one   size and the box of that image show from middle of the image i need some thing like this

Comment: for the image container i would suggest adding { background-size: cover;    position: relative; background-position: center;  background-repeat: no-repeat; overflow: hidden;  }